# How to read all files in a folder and subfolder using typescript with no html involved

Tags: typescript, file

I'd like to read all the contents of a textbundle file which is typically structured as follows:

[image]

I need to read each markdown and image file to then save it into Obsidian.

I've searched using Google and stack overflow, but can't find any helpful code examples or documentation. Often, results refer to Node.js, but not Javascript in the browser or Typescript.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [last example at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle#examples). -- Combined with the docs for [FileSystemHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle) explain pretty well, how to walk through the directory and how to read them.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. Do you know if these examples work for packaged bundles (e.g. .textbundle) or compressed archives (e.g. .zip files)?

Comment: AFAIK window.showDirectoryPicker() doesn't allow us to select a packaged file, namely a .textbundle file.